# How to resolve the issue of TypeScript recognizing type aliases `FirstMember<GenericityFunctionList>` as `unknown`?

Tags: typescript, frontend

I'm trying to write a function called `pipeline` that takes a series of functions as parameters and returns a new function. The new function should call these functions in the order they are passed and return the return type of the last function.

I'm using two type aliases, `FirstMember<T>` and `LastMember<T>`, to extract the first and last members of the function array `T`. However, when I try to use these type aliases, TypeScript recognizes them as the `unknown` type instead of the expected function types.

Here's my code example:

```js
type FirstMember<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer R, ...any[]] ? R : never
type LastMember<T extends any[]> = T extends [...any[], infer R] ? R : never

function pipeline<T extends Array<(...args: any) => any>>(...funcs: T) {
  // ...
  return function (
    this: any,
    ...args: Parameters<FirstMember<T>>
  ): ReturnType<LastMember<T>> {
    // ...
    return result
  }
}

/** !
 * The type 'FirstMember<T>' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: 
 * any) => any'.
 * Cannot assign type 'unknown' to type '(...args: any) => any'.
 */
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you!

expect no error report. Actually the intellisense of vscode works correctly even with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type FirstMember<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer R, ...any[]] ? R : never
type LastMember<T extends any[]> = T extends [...any[], infer R] ? R : never

function pipeline<T extends Array<(...args: any) => any>>(...funcs: T) {
  return function (
    this: any,
    ...args: Parameters<FirstMember<T> & ((...args: any) => any)>
  ): ReturnType<LastMember<T> & ((...args: any) => any)> {
   //
    return result;
  }
}
```

By adding `& ((...args: any) => any)`, we ensure that TypeScript recognizes these types as function types and not as the unknown type.